# Is it Possible to Externally Pull an Archer Report vi API?

Tags: rest, api, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have written some reports that contain data I'd like to programmatically access via API from an external system.  I can't find any documentation or sample code to do so via any one of the 3 APIs.  Has anyone used one of Archer's APIs to pull data from a report externally?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot pull reports via the REST API (yet), you'll have to use the Web Services API via the SearchRecordsbyReport method.

Comment: Is it still the same ?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same.  You have to use the Web Services API to pull report data.